# Get data from datatable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

In my data table footer callback I am getting data in this format:

```
Object { first: {…}, second: 100 }
```

From this :

```
paid = this.api().row().data();
console.log(paid)
```

What I actually want is the second value, but I am not able to get this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why not `paid.second`?

Comment: Thanx its done it was happening cos in first case i am getting the undefined in value bdw thanx...\